# CSS grid behaviour different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid, chromium

I have a css grid with 2 columns and 3 rows. The third row content is not always present because of an angular ngif clause. An image is present in the first column that spans the 3 rows. With all that said, I get 2 different results in Chrome (80.0.3987.87, which is the latest stable as I post) and Firefox.

Is there a way to control the rows so that it behaves like in Firefox, i.e. the third row grows when the image height is bigger than the 2 first row heights combined.

```css
.grid {
  width:400px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, auto) minmax(0, auto) minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.image {
  width:40px;
  height:100px;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1 / span 3;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.text1 {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:1;
}

.text2 {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text2">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/cadilhac/pen/yLNBmMd) that you can check in both Chrome and Firefox.

And here is an image to show the difference:

[image]

As you can see, Chrome increases equally the height of rows 1 and 2 (row 3 stays 0). Firefox increases only the height of row2, i.e. the last visible row with content.

Note that I tried setting grid-template-rows as "minmax(0, auto) minmax(0, auto) 1fr", but then row 3 will have a weird height that makes the grid height bigger than its content.

**Update**: Ah! Was able to try it on a previous Chrome version (79) and I get the same result as in Firefox this time. So it seems 80 changed it. Can some people here confirm?

Comment: Added an image to my OP

Comment: I see the firefox result on my Chrome. Can you add your version?

Comment: Added my chrome version, which is the latest as I post.

Comment: This is odd: on my computer, I get the exact same result in Firefox and Chrome... are your browsers up to date ? Do you have an extension installed on one of them that you wouldn't have on the other ?

Comment: `grid-template-rows: minmax(0, auto) minmax(0, auto) 1fr;` seems to fix it.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, see my updated post at the bottom.

Comment: @DamienVassart I disabled all extensions in Chrome and still get the same result.

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac I updated my chrome to 80 and I see the difference know.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your code like below. It seems to work the same in Chrome 80 and firefox. Worth to note that `1fr` is equal to `minmax(auto, 1fr)` which is indeed different from `minmax(0,1fr)` but still don't know exactly what makes both behave differently.

```css
.grid {
  width:400px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.image {
  width:40px;
  height:100px;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1 / span 3;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.text1 {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:1;
}

.text2 {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="text2">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was it for me, `minmax(0, fr)`, I'm on Win Chrome 121.0.6167.161 and Win FF 122.0.1. FF was working as calculated but Chrome was offsetting `fr` columns by few pixels (when testing responsive layout via zoom in/out). Using a min of 0 has them working congruently now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have mentioned the grid-template-rows for the container is invalid in chrome. I guess that's the issue

Try this css and see;

```
<style>
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.image {
    height: 100px;
    grid-row: 1/4;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.text1 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.text2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
</style>
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Can you explain what is invalid in Chrome and give a reference?

Comment: And note that it does not help. As soon as I add explicitely the third line, it's as if all rows were 1fr. So I need the grid-template-rows definition.

Comment: I think in that case you have to mention a CSS class with grid-column to 2 so that whatever new item you add goes automatically to the 2nd column.