# Chrome 80 css grid large descendants cause grid to grow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

When a grid has a fixed width and height, and a descendent of the grid has a width or height that is larger than that of the grid, the descendent forces the grid to 'grow' to fit it. In previous versions of Chrome (pre 80), and the latest version of Firefox (73.0 at the time of writing this) the descendants of the grid respected the grid's bounds. I've had a look the [release log](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/79.0.3945.130..80.0.3987.87?pretty=fuller&n=10000) for this update and can't seem to find any mention of changes to `grid` or `grid-template-rows/columns`.

- Expected Behaviour (Pre Chrome 80/Firefox)
  [image: Expected Behaviour (Pre Chrome 80/Firefox)]
- Actual Behaviour (Chrome 80)
  [image: Actual Behaviour (Chrome 80)]

Below is a minimal snippet to reproduce the problem.

```html
<div style="
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas:
        'header header'
        'form chart'
        'footer chart';
    grid-template-columns: minmax(250px,1fr) 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    height: 330px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 690px;
">
  <div style="background: red; grid-area: header;"></div>
  <div style="background: green; grid-area: form;"></div>
  <div style="background: blue;grid-area: chart">
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: purple; grid-area: footer;"></div>
</div>
```

My question is, is this a chrome bug, or is this chrome aligning to the css grid spec?

Comment: I can't speak to the spec but I'm seeing similar behaviour. Both Safari and Firefox behave correctly so it seems likely Chrome is either against the spec or the spec is ambiguous.

The problem seems to be Chrome's layout engine only considering the sizing of the first "row" in a div that spans two rows, and not spreading the available height across both sets of row constraints. I'd say it's worth filing a bug with Chromium

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @MattD, I've opened [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1053435) with the Chromium team and will update this issue as the bug progresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is the implementation of a [CSS Grid spec change](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#algo-spanning-flex-items) regarding the contribution of grid tracks spanning both finitely and infinitely sized tracks. I've [raised an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1051039) about this as well.

Gladly the Chromium development team [agreed that this change is not web compatible and causing too much breakage](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1051039#c36). It is already reverted on M80, M81 and M82 branches, and is going to be delivered with the reverted behaviour (pre-80-behaviour) [this week](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1051039#c59) in respin 116 (80.0.3987.116).

Edit: As of now, the new Chrome version is out and fixes these problems.

Edit 2: Because the Chromium team was the only browser team that actually implemented the aformentioned spec change, and they decided to revert it, the developer that implemented the changes raised an [issue@CSSWG](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4783). Link yourself to that if you wanna see where this is going.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The version should be available for download right now that reverts this issue.

I have found the following at google chromium src changes

> Revert "[css-grid] Accommodate spanning items crossing flexible tracks"
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/b1738fb61215bb8610e08f65de4d01681e250f7f

Also two more questions popped up with this same problem for those looking.

> [grid-template-columns in Chrome 80 inconsistently computed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60193734/12285468)
>
> [Why does Chrome 80 cause this grid-template-rows: auto problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60083540/12285468)

I am new here (answering) so I couldn't comment these under at the accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Update Below HTML

```html
<div style="
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas:
        'header header'
        'form chart'
        'footer chart';
    grid-template-columns: minmax(250px,1fr) 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    height: 330px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 690px;
">
  <div style="background: red; grid-area: header;"></div>
  <div style="background: green; grid-area: form;"></div>
  <div style="background: blue;grid-area: chart">
    <div style="height: 500px;display: inline;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: purple; grid-area: footer;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mehul , that does indeed fix the issue, however it's not clear to me why it fixes it it. On both Chrome and Firefox that element has `display: block` on it, but why does it behave differently on the two browsers? Is it a bug in Chrome or is Firefox mis-aligned with the css-grid spec?